Unable to achieve smooth transition with soft body returning to original shape after collision
I'm working with a soft body object colliding with a plane with a collider and trying to get the object to return smoothly to its original shape after the collision. I've followed advice to animate the minimum strength for the goal position toward 1, but the final part of the transition still feels abrupt. I try to make the transition as smooth as possible but there's a noticeable "hard" jump as the soft body snaps back to its original shape. The interpolation is set to linear.
Edit: I tried changing the interpolation to Bezier, but I'm still getting an abrupt transition.
Any suggestions how to make the transition smooth?
Thanks in advance!



Linear interpolation is intended to give an abrupt change! Try using Bezier instead.

Thanks for your comment. I changed the interpolation to Bezier, but I'm still getting an abrupt transition. Do you have any other ideas for a solution?

I'm not very familiar with those settings but could you try adding a keyframe with an intermediate setting for the 'goal position' just before the final frame?

I tried that, and it doesn't solve the problem :/

No idea in that case I'm afraid. :^(
